# How to Retrieve Log Level with "slog" Package in Go?

Tags: go, logging

I'm currently working on a project in Go, I've set up my logging with the "slog" package, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to retrieve the current log level programmatically.

I'd like to use something like:

```
lvl := slog.GetLogLevel()
```

But the aove function does not exists. Is it possible to retrieve programmatically the current log level please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slog.Default().Enabled()` to check if a certain level is to be logged. The log level is kept in the handler, and that does not provide a way of getting the handler options.